# Horizontal scroll bar doesn't have the correct width

Tags: html, css, scroll

I've used:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
}
```

to modify the style of my scrollbar

It worked for the vertical scroll on the right [scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYp5h.png) but not on the horizontal one.

I want that the booth have the same width. I've tried to see other posts but I didn't find anything like my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this.

```
/* For Webkit browsers */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px; /* Default width for both scrollbars */
}

/* For the vertical scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar-vertical {
    width: 8px;
}

/* For the horizontal scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar-horizontal {
    height: 8px; 
}
```